# Using deduced types in other function templates, argument

Tags: c++, function, templates

I have function template:

```
template<class Ty, 
typename std::enable_if< std::is_arithmetic<Ty>::value >::type* = nullptr >
inline void printBars(std::vector<Ty> const& y,
                  std::function<Ty(Ty)> const& alt);
```

I wonder if there is some approach to use the type deduced from first function argument in the second argument in order to make possible to use this function template in such way:

```
#include <cmath>
printBars(y, log10);
```

Is there?

Comment: You can make the second parameter an "undeducible context", for example wrapping `Ty` in an identity type-trait. I recommend against `std::function` in the signature, though, it's likely abuse. Take `... class F ... F alt ...` and *maybe* constrain / static-assert on `Callable<F(Ty)>`.

Comment: @Xeo, I have tried to use an identity type trait like this: `template<class T>
struct type_help
{
    typedef T type;
};

template<class Ty,
        typename std::enable_if< std::is_arithmetic<Ty>::value >::type* = nullptr >
inline void printBars(std::vector<Ty> const& y,
                      std::function<typename type_help<Ty>::type(typename type_help<Ty>::type)> const& alt );` but this didn't work out:(
I didn't understand your suggestion. Are you suggesting making a template class F with alt member function?

Comment: Check Alf's answer, he expands on what I mean in it. On the "identity" trait, I slipped up. [Here's an example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/09b1eb815af78588) - the whole parameter type needs to be wrapped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any computer science problem can be solved by another level of indirection.

In the public function just let the second argument be of type `U`, a second template parameter, and forward the call to the real function implementation.

This approach is also necessary if, for example, you want to differentiate between array and pointer argument.

---

Example.

```
namespace detail{
    template< class T >
    void printBars( std::vector<T> const& y, std::function<T(T)> const& alt)
    {
         // whatever.
    };
}  // namespace detail

template<
    class T, class U,
    class enabled = std::enable_if< std::is_arithmetic<T>::value >::type >
void printBars( std::vector<T> const& y, U const& alt )
{
    detail::printBars_impl<T>( y, alt );
};
```

Disclaimer: code not touched by compilar's hands, + just out bed (no coffee yet). ;-)

---

Thinking about it, the best here is probably to do as Xeo suggests and entirely dispense with the `std::function`, for it seem to just impose an unreasonable constraint on the caller; instead **just check** whether the argument supports what you want to use it for.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer! 
I'd like to be able use any kind off callable entity like lambda, regular function, function object. How can I check that?